# Check the state of a ToogleButton from another class

Tags: android, togglebutton

I would like to know how can I ask my app to check if my toggle buttons are checked or not so that when I press the play button, the app plays a sound only for the toggle buttons that are checked. (For instance, if button 1 and 3 are checked, when I press the play button it should do "Sound, silence, sound, silence" and loop until I press stop).

The problem is that right now when I press play, my app closes and I get the error `"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ToggleButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference"`.

I don't know how to resolve this problem. Here is my code :

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public ToggleButton button1, button2, button3, button4;
public Sampler mySample;
public ImageButton playButton;
public ImageButton stopButton;
public boolean playing;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    stopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    mySample = new Sampler(this);


    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mySample.play();
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mySample.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Sampler class :

```
public class Sampler extends Activity {

SoundPool sp;
private int snareId;
private Context mycontext;
public boolean playing;
public ToggleButton button1, button2, button3, button4;



public Sampler(Context appcontext) {

    this.mycontext = appcontext;

    sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    snareId = sp.load(mycontext, R.raw.snare, 1);


}


public void play() {

    playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        if (button1.isChecked()) {
            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (button2.isChecked()) {
            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (button3.isChecked()) {
            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (button4.isChecked()) {
            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(!playing){
                break;
        }
    }
}


public void stop(){

    playing = false;
}
```

Comment: You're getting a Null Pointer Exception because the buttons are initialised in your main activity and they don't belong in the Sampler Class. You can move the Play logic from Sampler Class to your main Activity, or pass references to the buttons as parameters to that method.

Comment: Sorry english isn't my native language and i'm super new to android programming so i'm not fully getting your advices. What do you mean by pass references to the buttons as parameters to that method? Does it mean that in my sampler class, my play method needs to be something like "public void play(boolean ToggleButton)"?

Comment: No need to apologise, your English is perfect! I was thinking something more like _public void play(ToggleButton button1, ....)_and then from your main activity: _mySample.play(button1, ...);_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Sampler` class, `button1` isn't initialised, resulting in `null object reference` error. To link up to MainActivity's `button1`, try this:

```
button1 = (((Activity)mycontext).findViewById(R.id.button1));
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that actually worked ! I've been stuck for days on this and it was really that simple, thanks a lot !
But now when i press play, i hear a sound but then my app seems to freeze and shuts down saying "app doens't respond". Do you have any clue on why it does that? I don't get a single error on android studio.

Comment: 2 possible causes. 1. It is likely caused by the `while (playing)` loop inside the `Play()`. Make use of classes such as `Timer`, `TimerTask`. Avoid applying programming practices from other languages to Android. 2. `SoundPool` has been replaced by `SoundPool.Builder()` in later API versions. By the way, if the original post is solved, start a new question since it is irrelevant to the title of the original post.